# How do I “undo” an animation in jQuery after hovering over an image?

Tags: jquery

I am making a website for someone relating to social media links, and I’m trying to get a few animations working for the website. The first half of the code works perfectly fine, but where it says “,function () {...” the code following it doesn’t seem to work. That code is supposed to “undo” the animation after the user has hovered over the “#logoImage”. (I apologize if I didn’ explain my problem and my goal very well.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#logoImage").hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "90px"
        });
        $("#logo").animate({
            width: "130px"
        });
        $("#twitter").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#youtube").fadeIn(1200);
    }),function () {
        $("#logoImage").animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
        $("#logo").animate({
            width: "40px"
            });
        $("#twitter").fadeOut(1200);
        $("#youtube").fadeOut(1000);
        };
</script>
```

Comment: The syntax is `hover(function() { ... }, function() { ... });`, whereas you currently have `hover(function() { ... }), function() {};` - note the misplaced `)`. Not to mention, simple animations like opacity, position, and height/width can be done with simple CSS transitions instead of relying on JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close at end the statement `)`

Corrected code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#logoImage").hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        left: "90px"
    });
    $("#logo").animate({
        width: "130px"
    });
    $("#twitter").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#youtube").fadeIn(1200);
},function () {
    $("#logoImage").animate({
        left: "0px"
    });
    $("#logo").animate({
        width: "40px"
        });
    $("#twitter").fadeOut(1200);
    $("#youtube").fadeOut(1000);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Hey Developer_29. In the future, if OP's issue can be solved by correcting a simple typographical mistake, consider marking the question *Off-Topic* instead of answering it (you'll see an Off-Topic rule specifically for "Simple Typographical Errors"). Thanks!